# Plane peel off's, climbs and dives

Tags: film-sound-design, planes

Hi all,

Imagine this shot: MCU of prop plane, it peels off to the left out of shot
Not having a real plane to play with I'm using stock library FX. Obviously planes don't really make that noise that we've come to associate with climbs and turns but it's a very firmly established cliché that I'd like to recreate. How do most people achieve it? Now I can imagine doing a certain amount with pitch-ing of engines and cutting into fly-by's, but I feel like I'm missing a trick?
cheers
g

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track...these types of effects are usually achieved by combining bys, approaches, sways, and steadies that may or may not be pitch shifted or otherwise affected. Also, experiment with layering other vehicles underneath the original sound for added dynamics, ie. a fast helicopter by may help you with a quick peel-off, or a jet by could help sell speed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try just plain-old volume automation.

If that doesn't do it, try adding a very light doppler effect to that.

But, a rapid increase and decrease of volume might go a long way to making your mundane engine drones have more life and movement.